# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is .......

```
  string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;
  string myDate = Request.QueryString["period"];

 string sql = "select FileName from tblProduct Where ProductName=" + PName;



    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan variable = dt2 - dt1;
    if (variable.TotalMinutes > 5)
    {
        //Response.Write("Download time is expired now");
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "Download time is expired now";
    }
    else
    {
        //string url1 = " http://www.shreehans.co.in/files/" + PName +"";
        //Response .Redirect ()
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "U can Still Download";
    }
```

And My URl is  with querystring parameters ......

mail.Body += string.Format("http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=" + DateTime.Now + "&ProductName=" + productName + "\">Demo Download");

Comment: What is myDate? Did you debug? Where is error thrown?

Comment: What are the value of `myDate` variable? Give some data examples into your question

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParse(...) instead of Convert.ToDateTime(...)

Comment: We need to see some sample data to properly advise. However.... these lines 1.) `string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;` 2.) `string sql = "select FileName from tblProduct Where ProductName=" + PName;` present a VERY serious risk of SQL injection. Someone could quite easily modify the productname querystring which is visible in the address bar to anything they like...

Comment: You are open for sql-injection, use sql-parameters! Consider a url-parameter `?ProductName='';Drop Table tblProduct;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you include date in url (query string), you should encode it like `Server.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

1. You're missing a `\"` when constructing the URI.
2. Your SQL code is susceptible to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your problem

```
mail.Body += 
   string.Format("http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=" + 
   DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + 
   "&ProductName=" + productName + "\">Demo Download");
```

Comment: and on download.aspx page  can i convert  that  date in any format?

Comment: Yes....you can use the same code: DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate); for conversion.